# updating existing site built in dreamweaver, handling DWT file

Tags: ftp, dreamweaver

I have a client that want's me to make a change to her OTHER site. The other site was built using Dreamweaver.

I guess (I don't build using Dreamweaver) the site pages are being controlled by the template file EXCEPT for the content that is specific to the page.

So I need to change the navigation items.

I found a folder called templates and in that folder is the template.dwt file. I tried copying that file to my desktop, then making the change and uploading back to the ftp site. Of course that had no effect on the nav items. My guess is the file on my desktop does not know to update the other pages as it doesn't know where those pages are.

So how do I go about making the changes to the files on the ftp site using the DWT file?

Do I have to download ALL the html files and the DWT files and somehow create a relationship so when I make the change to the DWT file it updates all the pages on my desktop THEN re-upload all those files back to the ftp site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you already figured this out, but just to be sure. You're question is right, the DW template works by when the template is modified (in DW) then you can update all the pages that are linked to it.

If you take the template out of DW and just modify and upload that alone, then nothing will happen to the other pages. So yea, if you know a way to create a link between the template and the other files outside of DW, then that is what you need to do. The other option is using DW and modify the template and then update the other pages, which is done in a semi-automatic way. Semi-automatic, meaning that DW gives the option to update the files either once you save the template or you can save the template and update the files later using DW.

And your guess is correct, the template modifies areas that are not specific to a page. Usually, this is done by creating Editable Regions in the template. Those regions are excluded from change when the template is modified.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a project in DW and put inside all the files that are "linked" with the template. They usually have tags inside that refer to the template.
Make sure that you keep the same file and folder distribution that the original had. If not, you could have a mess with relative links.
Then, with your template also in the project, open and modify it. 
When you save the template, DW will ask you for scan and update related files, if you are lucky it will find and update all of them.